# OpenBSD unable to install therubyracer gem ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, openbsd

I am trying host OpenSourceBilling application built using Ruby on Rails framework to OpenBSD server. When i try to install gems using `bundle install` command, I get following error on therubyracer gem installation:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem.
```

However,

```
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.7 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a port available: http://openports.se/search.php?so=therubyracer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to install `therubyracer` gem in `OpenBSD`. As a workaround, I  replaced it with the `nodejs` javascript runtime:

```
gem 'node'
```

Make sure to remove the `gem 'therubyracer'` line.

Answer (score 2):

update `libv8` to point to version `~> 3.11.8.3` in your gemfile
  this will work.....

Comment: then you can use node.js as an alternate solution. visit this link..
https://nodejs.org/

Comment: But my Gemfile specify 'therubyracer' gem. If i removed this gem, i have to install nodejs or any other javascript runtime manually.